# Stuck ubuntu logo screen while trying to install from usb

Tags: boot, usb, screen

I have a notebook with FreeDOS system and I'm trying to install ubuntu 14.04. When I prove "Try ubuntu without installing", it works perfectly, but when I go to the install option, it appears the screen with the ubuntu logo all the time. First it seems to be charging, but then all dots are orange and that is like it remains.

I've proved with the 15.04 version and it happens the same thing.

Help, please!!

Comment: First thank you for answering! But I don't know how to do that (I don't know if it is because I'm almost new in ubuntu or because of the language). I'm already in Ubuntu with "try ubuntu...", now what is exactly the steps??

Comment: OMG, I haven't see this icon :S. It seems that is working (I'm praying a lot xD). Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick workaround : Boot in **Try Ubuntu without installing** then open the installer included in the live environment :

[image]

Hope this will work for you.